# Is this question about Wattpad / Goodreads on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

"Software for syncing my [Wattpad](https://www.wattpad.com/) reading progress on [Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/)?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say yes, it is on topic.

Although you would have to add details such as which platform you wish to run the software on and whether you want to pay for it or not.

The simple wording you have in this question on meta would probably be closed as "Unclear" without those qualifications.

Comment: Thank you. Just done it (http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25161/software-for-syncing-my-wattpad-reading-progress-on-goodreads)

Does it satisfy the requirements for an on-topic question here?

Comment: @Dawny33 Looks on-topic to me, and it seems to have enough information.